# JAX-RS Jersey - Web service resources cooperation

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jersey, jax-rs

I am implementing a restful web service using Jersey (Jax-rs).

I have two resources:

**/news** : returns a list of news

**/countries**: returns a list of countries

And I want to implement something to allow me to get the news of a certain country.

Something like : **/countries/{countryId}/news**

How, and where I should implement it?

**News Resource Code:**

```
@Path("/news")
public class NewsResource {

    NewsService newsService = new NewsService();

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        public List<News> getNews(){
            return newsService.getNews();
    }

}
```

**Countries Resource Code:**

```
@Path("/countries")
public class CountriesResource {

    CountriesService countriesService = new CountriesService();

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        public List<Countries> getCountries(){
            return countriesService.getCountries();
    }

}
```

I can do it by adding the following method to the **Countries** class.

```
@Path("/{countryId}/news")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<News> getCountryNews(@PathParam("countryId") int countryId){
        return countryService.getCountryNews(countryId);
    }
```

But, this way, my **Countries** resource is returning news, which I don't find logical!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here comes the solution:

**News Resource Code:**

```
@Path("/news")
public class NewsResource {

    NewsService newsService = new NewsService();

    @GET
    public List<News> getNews(@PathParam("countryId") int countryId){
        if(countryId==null){
            return newsService.getNews();
        }else{
            return newsService.getCountryNews(countryId);
        }
    }

}
```

**Countries Resource Code:**

```
@Path("/countries")
public class CountriesResource {

    CountriesService countriesService = new CountriesService();

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        public List<Countries> getCountries(){
            return countriesService.getCountries();
    }

    @Path("/{countryId}/news")
    public NewsResource getCountryNews(){
        return new CountryResource();
    }

}
```

When calling **/news** since **countryId** is null, we get all news.

When calling **countries/{countryId}/news**, we call the **news** resource from the **countries** resource, and since **countryId** contains the id of the country for which we want to get the news, we call the **getCountryNews(countryId)** method.